# Vectortransformation inside Cases condition very slow

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, conditional

I have the following piece of code

```
all[phi_, theta_, alpha_] := 
EulerMatrix[{-(phi + 
   90) Degree, theta Degree, -(180 - alpha) Degree}, {3, 2, 1}] 

condition = Cases[data, { _, _, x_, _, _, vx_, vy_, vz_, _} /;
85 < VectorAngle[all[Phi[x], Theta[x], Alpha[x]].{0, 0, -1}, 
{vx, vy, vz}]/Degree < 95]
```

with `Phi[x]`, `Theta[x]` and `Alpha[x]` defined as `Piecewise` functions that give back angles in degrees along x. `"data"` is a list of particles, each with different positions, velocities and other properties.

What the code does is filter out all particles in data, whose velocity vector is out of a certain field of view.

Since the orientation of the field of view is not constant, but changing depending on the x coordinate inside my reference system, I need to apply a transformation matrix to the field of view-system inside my condition.

```
VectorAngle[all[Phi[x], Theta[x], Alpha[x]].{0, 0, -1},{vx, vy, vz}]
```

But the way I'm doing it seems very slow. For a 500k long list, it takes about 10 min. The main problem seems to be the calling of the rotation matrix inside VectorAngle. Is there a faster way?

Edit:

An example of the entries in `data` :

`{0, 3.5104e-07, 45.351, -0.654687, 0.300059, 6.81731, -1.25439, -4.13684, 8.07234}`

The first entry identifies the particles species, the second is a numerical weight, the last entry is actually the magnitude of the particles velocity.

Here's how I defined `Phi[x]` (I didn't include all conditions):

```
Phi[x_] := 
Piecewise[{{140, x < -14.},{125.,-14. <= x < -12.},{90.,12.<= x <-9.5},
{160., -9.5 <= x < -2.},{180.,-2. <= x < 4.5}}
```

`Alpha[x]`and `Theta[x]`are defined in the exact same way, just other numbers. And the intervals covered in the conditions do not overlap completely inbetween the three.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of data in order to give an impression how this looks like? What are the first two and the last entry? And what are `Phi[x]`, `Theta[x]`, and `Alpha[x]`. It would be nice to have their definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Just some first guesses:

First, `VectorAngle` is notoriously slow; that's something that actually rather inacceptable. Here is a compiled version

```
cAngle = Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{lu, lv},
   lu = Sqrt[Abs[u.u]];
   lv = Sqrt[Abs[v.v]];
   If[lu > 1. 10^-12 && lv > 1. 10^-12,
    ArcCos[u.v/lu/lv],
    0.5 Pi
    ]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True
  ]
```

Second, `Degree` is nice to have but I it may also slow things down. So I removed it.

Third, the code about the `EulerMatrix` needs only to be applied once symbolically. (Quite likely, it is the slowest part in the code). I put this together with a lot of other things to be done into a `CompiledFunction`. If `Phi`, `Theta`, and `Angle` should be really only `Piecewise`, then this should work well with `Compile`. (Not having your code, I cannot check this... too bad.)

```
Phi = x \[Function] x;
Theta = x \[Function] x;
Alpha = x \[Function] x;
With[{code = 
    Simplify[
     EulerMatrix[{-(Phi[x] + 90) Degree, 
         Theta[x] Degree, -(180 - Alpha[x]) Degree}, {3, 2, 1}
     ].{0, 0, -1} /. Degree -> Pi/180.]},
  u = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
  ];
```

Some random example (which is also pretty meaningless without real example data... again too bad). I use `Clip` to set all entries outside of the desired interval to `-42.` (all other entries remain unchanged). Afterwards, `Cases` can detect detect the entries different from `-42`.

```
data = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, {5000000, 9}];
condition = Cases[
    Clip[cAngle3[u[data[[All, 3]]], data[[All, 6 ;; 8]]], {85 Pi/180.,
       95 Pi/180.}, {-42., -42.}],
    Except[-42.]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.08703, Null}

Runs in roughly a second. Unfortunately, I cannot check if this is the correct result. Guess why. No example data.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can't comment my post because I made it before registering. 
The answer of @Henrik Schumacher works very well indeed and should be approved.
Here's how I applied his ideas:

```
condition = 
Cases[data, { _, _, x_, _, _, vx_, vy_, vz_, _} /; 
85 < cAngle[u[x], {vx, vy, vz}]/Degree < 95];`
```

using his definitions for `u`and `cAngle`. This gives me exactly what I wanted, a list of the remaining elements in `data` that fulfill the asked condition, done in negligible time (about 5 seconds). Thank you very much!